# Design recommendation for an android app

Tags: android, design-patterns

I am planning to develop an android app. This will be my first app if I upload it.
I have pretty good idea , what my app should do , But I lack design skills and have no one to ask around. So asking android experts here.

App objective : very simple , have a listview with proper titles , on clicking it(list items) , it will show an appropriate image.

Approaches which I thought.

1. Have a relation between title(or a tag) and image names and have all images in drawable folder. whenever list item is clicked, point to appropriate drawable and show it.
   Pros: easy to do it.
   Cons: Seems like not scalable.
2. Store id,title,drawable reference( drawable ids ) in database and use it.
   Pros: (different approach than prev one)
   Cons: Creating database is painful if number of items are more !
   I want some guidance in this approach, how people create huge database(for android) which
   works offline.
3. Have a server, database there , provide an API for my app , whenever update is pressed ,
   local database is synced !
   Pros: Seems like scalable approach.
   Cons: Hell lot of work for a simple app !

   Should one consider storing images in database as BLOB data ?

   Or none of these approach is correct.

Any advice will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many images are we talking about? Is this set of images static? If so, I'd go with the first option. Especially if these images are small in size.

If you have to modify the set of images (add/remove images from it somehow), and/or the images are huge I'd use the SD card solution too.

Comment: Number of images will be more and quality of images will be moderate which will be good on most of the mobile phones. So approach would be to ask the user to fetch data once he installs and my app should download some tar file and untar and save it in sdcard and use it.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with first option with storing the images on the SD card in a folder.